# How do I pass security details from a Spark client to a Spark cluster and on to HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

Could anyone provide any useful resources describing security best practices in a distributed Spark environment?

I'm building a simple lab environment that looks a little bit like this:

SPARK_CLIENT
|
SPARK_MASTER   -> SPARK_WORKER[n]
|
HIVE -> HDFS

For now the workloads mainly involve processing files stored on the HDFS, performing some transformations, and then writing the files back to HDFS as Deltas. In the real world, you'd have different files on HDFS accessible to different people, so there has to be a way to pass authentication details from client to Spark to HDFS. In Databricks you'd maybe use an app registration and Oauth2 passed to the file system via conf settings, but can anyone point me towards the correct procedure in an on-prem, classic Spark 3.3.1 environment? I think I need to be looking at Spark delegation tokens maybe?

Authentication and authorisation

Comment: The answer is Kerberos, but that's too broad too detail in full for Stackoverflow

Comment: Comments from deleted answer => [Apache Spark documentation on security](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html) & [Hadoop documentation on security](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html)

Answer (score 1):

@OneCricketeer is correct.

Here's some links to get you started.

- [Apache spark security documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html)
- [Apache Spark Component Guide](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.3/bk_spark-component-guide/content/configuring-kerb.html)
- [Kerberos with Spark](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-conductor/2.4.0?topic=group-submitting-spark-batch-applications-kerberos-authentication)

You will also need to follow relevant documentation for Hive, HDFS, YARN, and other components on enabling Kerberos for those.

Comment: The HDP docs may be outdated, btw. For example, `/usr/hdp/current` path wouldn't exist in a self-installed Spark/Hadoop cluster

Comment: Thanks guys, you've set me off down the right path.